# C# get character after a character from a string

Tags: c#, string, char

```
string dex = "ab43kjh43434v34b";
```

How can I get every second character into another string from the string above?
For example:

```
string dex1 = "b3j4443b";
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve this problem?  What problems have you come across in your own attempted solution?

Comment: i tried to split the string but i couldn't

Comment: why you required this

Comment: i'm making a project and i need in my project this function

Comment: it doesn't fair that you guys voted my question down, because i was just asking this, i really need it.

Comment: @Sedax I think it was voted down because you did not mention anything you tried yourself (I'm not one of the downvoters)

Comment: You got down voted because you didn't show any effort or describe problems you were having with your approach. StackOverflow is not Mechanical Turk for your code.

Comment: Oke sorry about that, i'm new and i didn't know how i really should have been writing.

Comment: @Sedax Usually you write your question, what you tried and did not work and the expected input/outputs. Your first version did not even have the expected output, so it was pretty hard to understand what you were asking.

Comment: Oke Luc i got it now. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string dex = "ab43kjh43434v34b";
var dex1 = String.Join("", dex.Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 1));
```

Comment: Why didn't you use indexed `Where`  instead?

Comment: Rather than mutating an external variable and relying on its side effects, you can simply use the overload of `Where` that provides the item's index to the predicate.  Additionally, rather than using `Join`, with a blank separator, you can use `Concat`, as it both conceptually represents the operation you're performing (you're concatting the items, not joining them with a separator) and marginally improves performance.

Comment: If we're being clever, why don't we just do `dex.Where(c => ++i % 2 == 0)` and not join on an empty string.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Because that doesn't return a string.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. You are correct.

Comment: `new string(dex.Where(c => ++i % 2 == 0).ToArray())` does.

This is for *small values* of clever.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot And why is that preferable to using `Concat`?

Comment: @Servy It isn't, it was preferable to joining on an empty string - I didn't see your response in the comments until now, and I didn't think of `Concat` at the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i <= dex.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 != 0) continue;
    result.Append(dex[i]);
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of repeatedly recreating a new string.

Comment: @Guilherme you don't need `.ToString()` in *result.Append*.

Comment: @L.B oh, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: this is good too Guilherme, thanks.

Comment: You misspelled `Length`.

Comment: You *still* misspelled `Length`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex works, too:

```
string EveryOtherCharacter( string s , int modulo2 )
{
  string value = Regex.Replace( s , "." , m => m.Index & 1 == 1 ? m.Value : "" )) ;
  return value ;
}
```

Though I think, you'll find avoiding LINQ-like cleverness and sticking to simplicity will yield the most efficiency. Here's the simple and obvious generic version:

```
string SelectEveryNthCharFromString( string s, int n , int r )
{
  if ( s == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("s") ;
  if ( n < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n") ;
  if ( r < 0 || r > n-1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("r") ;

  StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder( 1 + s.Length / n ) ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < s.Length ; ++i )
  {
    if ( i % n != r ) continue ;
    buffer.Append(s[i]) ;
  }

  return buffer.ToString() ;
}
```

Comment: A downvote? Really? Any explanation -- I'm interested as to the rationale here.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat a string as an array of characters, for instance `dex[0]` will give you `a` in your example. That, a for(each)-loop and perhaps the `Length` property should be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: yes this is a good ideea too, thanks C.Evenhuis.

Comment: I wonder if I got a downvote just because I didn't provide a copy-pasteable answer :)

Comment: Fixed it for ya. You provided as much answer as the O.P. provided attempted solution B^)